# Passing Session Variable with Ajax and iframe does not work

Tags: php, html, ajax, session-variables

**I´m trying to pass a variable from a Page (values of a form) to a php page via a session.
Between that I have an iframe that opens another html page after the form is sent and makes an ajax request to the php page but it always fails and gives me this:**

> Notice: Undefined index: Flightnumber1
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Datetime1

The Session does not work.
If I don´t make an ajax request and just put the php code of my php file inside my iframe-html-page the session works, but I really need it to be an ajax request.

I tried changing the header as suggested on stackoverflow to:

```
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
```

I also checked if thrid party cookies are allowed in my testing browser, even if I don´t see the meaning of that, as it´s a session not a cookie but it was suggestet here too.

I even tried passing the variable with a session to the iframe-page and then made a new variable out of it and passed that one to the php page, but still no positive result.

This is the **first page**:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $_SESSION['Flightnumber1'] = $_POST['Flightnumber1'];
        $_SESSION['Datetime1'] = $_POST['Datetime1'];
    }
?>

<form target="iframe" method="post" action="iframe.html">
    <input id="Flightnumber1" name="Flightnumber1" type="text" />
    <input id="Datetime1" name="Datetime1"  type="text"/>
    <input id="Submit-Prufbox" name="Submit" type="submit" onclick='document.getElementById("iframe").src="iframe.html"; $("#iframe").show();' />
</form>

<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

This is the page that opens in the iframe after the form is submited:
**iframe.html**

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<script>
    $( "#result" ).load( "AjaxRequestPage.php" );
</script>
```

This is the page where the ajax requests:
**AjaxRequestPage.php**

```
session_start();
$regValue = $_POST['Flightnumber1'];
$regValue2 = $_POST['Datetime1'];

phpcode;
phpcode;
phpcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your AjaxRequestPage.php you need to call the variables through $_SESSION

```
session_start();
$regValue = $_SESSION['Flightnumber1'];
$regValue2 = $_SESSION['Datetime1'];
```

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh, I changed that once for testing and forgot to change it back, but still thank you very much, tried finding the problem since yesterday evening. Thank you :)

Comment: No worries its normal. Sometimes we just need a second pair of eyes! 
Accept answer please :)

Comment: @Serranp, dude 3 hours past and I get same error again, what is going on ? I checked if the code is the same, do you see anything else?

Comment: no, I know now why, it´s because the form is not posted to the iframe, and your fix only worked because I tried it without iframe